# keyword symbol enclosed by two pipes

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

Suppose a function `fun` in the code below, my goal is evaluating `expr2` below.

```
(defun fun (&key (x nil)) x)
(defparameter expr1 (list 'fun :x 2))
(defparameter expr2 (list 'fun (intern "x" "KEYWORD") 2))
```

As expected, `(eval expr1)` gives `2`, but `(eval expr2)` gives an error like

> *** - FUN: illegal keyword/value pair :|x|, 2 in argument list.
>         The allowed keywords are (:X) The following restarts are available: ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop

Why does this error occurs? and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that normally in Common Lisp every symbol is translated to uppercase letters when read (this is the standard behaviour, and can be changed), so that:

```
(defun fun (&key (x nil)) x)
(defparameter expr1 (list 'fun :x 2))
```

is actually read as:

```
(DEFUN FUN (&KEY (X NIL)) X)
(DEFPARAMETER EXPR1 (LIST 'FUN :X 2))
```

while `intern` gets a string as first parameter and does not transform it, so that in your example "x" is interned as the symbol `:x`, which is different from the symbol `:X` (and this is the reason of the error). Note that when a symbol with lowercase letters is printed in REPL, it is surrounded by pipe characters (`|`), like in `|x|`, so that, when read again, lowercase characters are unchanged:

```
CL-USER> :x
:X
CL-USER> :|x|
:|x|
CL-USER> (format t "~a" :|x|)
x
NIL
```

To solve your problem, you can simply write the string directly in uppercase:

```
(defparameter expr2 (list 'fun (intern "X" "KEYWORD") 2))
```

and then `(eval expr2)` works as intended.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `\` and `|` are escape characters in symbols:

```
? 'foo\xBAR
FOO\xBAR

? '|This is a symbol|
|This is a symbol|

? ':|This is a keyword symbol with spaces and Capital letters!!!|
:|This is a keyword symbol with spaces and Capital letters!!!|

? 'what|? wow |this| also works|?
|WHAT? wow THIS also works?|
```